# Sql performance on vista machine client

Tags: sql, windows-vista

I have an application written in a language called magic. This application uses MSSQL Server. When it is deployed where the client is on vista machine, and the server is on a remote machine, the performance is dramatically degraded.
When that same application is used from an XP client, with the db on remote machine – the performance is ok.
Also when the server and client are both on a vista machine, it works ok.

This makes me think that it's some kind of network protocol problem, but I can't seem to solve it.

Help will be appreciated

Note that the vista is 64 bit, and that the application is 32bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is cause by some strange vista behaviour around named computers.

You can either use ip instead of names, or 
change the following vista setting:

Start Run ->

gpedit.msc ->

Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Network\DNS Client\Turn off Multicast Name Resolution = Enabled

Answer (score 0):

Are you connecting via an IP Address or a host name maybe looking up the hostname is taking an age? I assume the vista and xp machine are in the same location.

Make sure the vista and xp machine use the same dns settings. perhaps its failing on a reverse dns lookup.

Comment: I am using the hostname, but that would only create problems in the connection creation - not on every select.

Comment: They are using the same dns settings, and it's all automatic ip assignemnt

Answer (score 0):

Many constraints... mainly internet speed if your remote database communicates through internet.

Comment: It is not over an internet connection.

All the scenarios mentioned in my question are all on the same network, at my office

Comment: I have inspected them, the queries are the same from xp, and from vista. 
Also when the server is local on the vista, I get good performance - so it's not in the profiler